# What is the meaning of “overbuffering” in RUDP?

Tags: networking, network-programming, udp, network-protocols

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliable_User_Datagram_Protocol

In order to ensure quality, it extends UDP by means of adding the following features:

Acknowledgment of received packets

Windowing and flow control

Retransmission of lost packets

**Overbuffering (Faster than real-time streaming)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend reading the IETF draft: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-sigtran-reliable-udp-00

The draft does not talk about any mechanism like overbuffering. However, RUDP does maintain an explicit account of out-of-order messages and an extra buffer for it. The receiver also uses an explicit ACK to tell the sender about the out of order messages received; they call it Extended ACK. TCP does not use any explicit EACK like this but some of the out-of-order messages are reported using SACK option.